# Flyback Converter - MOSFET Power Dissipation

Tags: power-supply, power, power-electronics

I am trying to calculate the total losses in the primary-side MOSEFT of a flyback converter.

Here is what I have:

P_total = P_cond + P_switching

P_cond = I_d(rms)^2 * R_ds(on)

P_switching = P_on + P_off

P_on = I_d(on) * V_dd * T_on * 0.5 * F_sw

P_off = I_d(on) * V_dd * T_off * 0.5 * F_sw

I_d(on) = I_d(rms) / sqrt(D_max)

Does this look correct?

Comment: What is the current ripple fraction -- is this deep CCM, or DCM or what? What transistor type -- idealized (fixed capacitance and gm), planar, superjunction?